# PIP Path, Unable to Change PIP

Tags: python, pip

So when I run: `which pip` I'm returned with the the following path: `/Users/user/opt/miniconda3/bin/pip`. Same for `which pip3`as well.

When I go to check my pip.config I'm returned with the following response:
`$ pip config list`
`global.target='/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages'` Again, I also am returned with the same path with the `pip3` version as well.

The main dilemma I run into is when I install packages from PyPi they don't seem to install into my global target when I go to use Python 3.10. For instance, recently I was trying to work with DearPyGui via `pip` but I was unsuccessful in doing so due to the package not being found. Is there something I am missing here? In the past I had Conda installed for a project I was working on, but I since then have moved away from using Conda and no longer have it installed.

Comment: If I understand you correct '/Users/user/opt/miniconda3/bin/pip' does not exist? What does 'echo $PATH' say?

Comment: Here is the output :`/Users/user/opt/miniconda3/bin:/Users/user/opt/miniconda3/condabin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/opt/local/bin`

Comment: I think I may have found an answer to my problem. Since I have multiple Python versions installed they say to move from using standand `pip` to using `python -m pip` so it will point to where ever my python path is pointing. So then i made an alias in .zshrc file as `alias pip='python -m pip`so I don't have to type it out longhand. Thanks for your assistance.